# Postgresql VACUUM FULL ANALYZE side effect

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, optimization

Running `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` will free up space in your database by rebuilding indexes.

Does it have any impact on index cache hit ratio or can we safely assume that running `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` rebuilds the same indexes, just in a more compressed way?